# Checking user input against Access database

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access

I've been trying to create a query to check if the inputted PayrollNo is already present in the Datafile, and if it is, for the button (BtnContinue) to send the user to a different form. I've been stuck for a few days so any help would be great as I'm no doubt close to where I need it to be.

Code is as follows, to be exe. on BtnContinue_Click

```
private void BtnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    using (OleDbConnection Connstring = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        conn.Open();
        String query = ("SELECT count(*) as PayrollNo FROM [Employee] where PayrollNo = @PayrollNo");
        OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        using (OleDbDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                PayrollExists form = new PayrollExists();
                form.Tag = this;
                form.Show(this);
                Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                EmployeeDetails form = new EmployeeDetails();
                form.PassValueFirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
                form.PassValueLastName = txtLastName.Text;
                form.PassValuePayrollNo = txtPayrollNo.Text;
                form.Tag = this;
                form.Show(this);
                Hide();
            }                         
        }
    }
```

Like I say been stuck on this for a while now so any help would be brilliant

Comment: Two connection instances?

Comment: @UweKeim Yeah, looks like `Connstring` never used in OP's code `conn` should wrapped with `using` statement instead of it :)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can see, you *never* add your `@PayrollNo` parameter and it's value to your command.

Also using [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executescalar) instead of `ExecuteReader` would be better since your query returns one column with one row.

```
dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = yourPayrollNo;
// I assumed your column type is Integer
```

and check it like;

```
int count = (int)dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
if(count > 0)
{
   // Exist
}
```

And `Connstring` connection seems *unnecessary* because you never use it in your code. Replace it with `conn` which is defined one line above.

As a full example;

```
var conStr = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
using(var dbCmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   dbCmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM [Employee] where PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";
   dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = yourPayrollNo;

   conn.Open();
   int count = (int)dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
   if(count > 0)
   {
      PayrollExists form = new PayrollExists();
      form.Tag = this;
      form.Show(this);
      Hide();
   }
   else
   {
      EmployeeDetails form = new EmployeeDetails();
      form.PassValueFirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
      form.PassValueLastName = txtLastName.Text;
      form.PassValuePayrollNo = txtPayrollNo.Text;
      form.Tag = this;
      form.Show(this);
      Hide();
   }      
}
```

By the way, [`OleDbCommand` does *not* support named parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters). When you add parameters to `OleDbCommand`, only matter is their orders. Since you have only one parameter in your example, that's not an issue here but be aware of it.

Comment: How would I go about changing my code for it to work effectively?

Comment: @Josh You would add additional lines of code to your code.

Comment: Soner, I'm using the line you've provided and I'm getting an error over 'cmd' the name 'Cmd' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Josh I added as a full example. Take a look.

Comment: Again the same line, cmd, throwing up an error, is there a using.system or something i'd need?

Comment: int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: @Josh It should be `dbCmd` not `cmd`. Fixed now.

Comment: Soner, You should feel really good right now. Thanks for all the help :)